# Godot 3.2.1 - 3D Missile Guidance with Angle Rate Limits

Tags: godot

Does anyone know how to do something like 3D missile guidance in Godot 3.2 that allows for angle rate limits?  Everything I've found online uses something like `global_transform = global_transform.look_at(aTarget.global_transform.origin)`.
However, that instantaneously rotates the transform, which is very unrealistic.  I've also seen some mentions of using the `Quat` class where you then use `aQuatFrom.slerp(aQuatTo,aAmount)`; however, that has also not worked for me (although, maybe I'm just misunderstanding something there?).

Let's just say, for the sake of this conversation, that there is a `Missile.gd` file that contains at least the following data members that get initialized on instantiation:

```
extends KinematicBody
var _velocity : Vector3
var _speed : float
var _max_angle_rate : float
var _target : Object
```

How would you calculate the new velocity at each time step?  I've tried using Transforms, Quaternions, and Euler angles, but have had no luck with any of them.  Some attempts will seem to work on occasion, but never in every case.  I've been going at this for a while now with no luck, so I'd be very grateful to hear any help you may have to offer.

To this point, a large part of the struggle is just how to modify the data that I need to modify. I can do vector math, but I can't seem to get the data I need out of Godot.  I'm not all that familiar with Quaternions, so maybe there's a solution there that I'm missing, I'm not sure.  That said though, I think a solution for a "pure pursuit" guidance (i.e. just point at the target) is sufficient for now.  Once I can get that, I can work on implementing other guidance algorithms.

Thank you for any/all help!

Answer (score 0):

Quaternions are indeed useful for this kind of job.

In the missile referential, you could use the *vector product* (aka cross product), between the *forward direction* and the direction of the target, which would yield an axis for the Quaternion. The sign of the *dot product* of the *up direction* and the aforementioned *cross product* will yield the sign of the Quaternions' angle.

---

You could perhaps also interpolate between the current transform of the missile and the transform you obtain with `look_at()`, using `Transform.interpolate_with()`.